# removing element from array using splice

Tags: javascript

Supposed I have a response of

[image]

and I'm looping it via and push the pic.id on files array

```
files = []

response.data[0].pics.forEach(function(pic, i){
      let div = makeButtons(response.data[0].pics, files, imgPrevEdit);
      files.push(pic.id);
});
```

so after pushing the file array will become like this

[image]

the make button function is use to delete that certain element on the array using splice function

```
makeButtons: function(file, store, elem) {
    let button = document.createElement("button");
    button.classList.add('position-absolute','x', 'rounded-circle');
    button.type = "button";
    button.innerHTML= "x";

    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        elem.removeChild(div);
        store.splice(store.indexOf(file), 1);
    });

    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add('col', 'mt-2');
    div.appendChild(button);
    return div;
},
```

However when i click the button it always start at the end of files array it doesnt find the specific key and delete it

any idea how can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it always start at the end of files array

I think it happens because `store.indexOf(file)` returns `-1`. In this case [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> will begin that many elements from the end of the array (with origin
>   -1, meaning -n is the index of the nth last element and is therefore equivalent to the index of array.length - n)

Why `store.indexOf(file)` returns `-1`? Because you pass `response.data[0].pics` as `file` argument, but you actually push `pic.id` to `files` which you pass as `store`:

```
let div = makeButtons(response.data[0].pics, files, imgPrevEdit);
files.push(pic.id);
```

Comment: what should i pass as file argument? im confused

Comment: @Beginner try to pass `pic.id`